# Is gravity just the result of bending the space?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

so einstein said that space is a thing and that if you put a heavy object in it it will bend it, just like a trampoline when you jump on it. and he said that gravity is just the result of another object being near you. the object will rotate around you because you bent the trampoline

is this the commonly accepted answer about what gravity is?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13839/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Space-time, not 'space'. And the XKCD strip in the above link sums it up well: the 'bending' of space-time is a useful way of visualising things, but it doesn't *mean* anything since we don't know what space-time actually is (beyond a useful mathematical construct). Energy changes the space-time metric. That's it.

Comment: but it still suggests that gravity is just a consequence and not a force like many other people think?

Comment: Related questions: [Gravitation is not force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33875/gravitation-is-not-force) and [Why do we still need to think of gravity as a force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61899/why-do-we-still-need-to-think-of-gravity-as-a-force)